# Corrupted AWS CLI DynamoDB Table (+doesn't update on DynamoDB website)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I tried to put an item into my DynamoDB table from my CLI. My command prompt gives me no errors. But when I refresh the DyanamoDB website, I don't see the item added in the "Global Secondary Index". When I try "aws dynamodb scan --table-name temp", some numbers and "<-" show up, not the item I put in.

Screenshot of my commands:
[image]

My dynamodb.json file:

```
{
    "name": {"S": "Suguru Chhaya"},
    "email": {"S": "suguruchhaya@gmail.com"}
}
```

Comment: Those are [terminal control sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) e.g. `ESC[1m` for bold and `ESC[34m` for foreground blue. Your item does, however, appear to be listed. Somehow, the control sequences must have been disabled in your terminal. Perhaps related to your apparent use of Windows 11, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the formatting is due to terminal control sequences so the table was working correctly.

Actually, the "Global Secondary indexes" was the wrong page to look at... I should have went to "Overview"->"View Items".